# Any iOS UI control similar to the volume change popup?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I'd like to notify my users when something like a request failure occurs. However, I don't want to interrupt the user by using a popup style alert. I'm looking for something like when you change the volume on the device and that translucent icon pops up and fades away after a second or two. During the time the icon is showing, the user can still interact with the app as if it weren't there.

I looked in the HIG, but I couldn't find any such UI control that is native to iOS. Are there any good open source controls that do this?

[image]

Comment: not sure if they have open source controls to do that, but should not be hard to create..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an excellent control for a HUD-style popup called [**`SVStatusHUD`**](https://github.com/samvermette/SVStatusHUD).  I belive it does exactly what you're looking for:

[image]